# How do I send htm file to socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to send this htm file to a web browser and have the browser display the contents of the file. When I run my code, all that happens is the browsers displays the name of the htm file and nothing else.

```
try 
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        String input = in.readLine();

        while (!input.isEmpty()) 
        {
            System.out.println("\tserver read a line: " + input);
            input = in.readLine();
        }

        System.out.println("");

        File myFile = new File ("hello.htm");

        out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
        out.println("\r\n");
        out.write(myFile);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("\ncaught exeception: " + e + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: You need to open and read the file, not just send the name: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File)

Comment: What do you believe `out.write(myFile)` does, and why do you believe so? It seems you're wrong, so re-think what you're doing, e.g. **read the documentation** of what `write(...)` does and what a `File` object is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually write the contents of the file to the stream:

```
...
BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
out.write("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
//Tell the end user how much data you are sending
out.write("Content-Length: " + myFile.length() + "\r\n");
//Indicates end of headers
out.write("\r\n");
String line;
while((line = in2.readLine()) != null) {
    //Not sure if you should use out.println or out.write, play around with it.
    out.write(line + "\r\n");
}
//out.write(myFile); Remove this
out.flush();
out.close();
...
```

The above code is just an idea of what you really should be doing. It takes into account the HTTP protocol.

Comment: You should use neither, anywhere. The line terminator in HTTP is specified as `\r\n`, not as whatever `println()` produces on your system.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. I suppose `out.write(line + "\r\n");` should fix it? I have also mentioned the code is an idea and does not take into account the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Yes, and the same on the header lines.

Comment: Sorry about the out.write() stuff. I was messing around with something and when I posted this question I forgot to put it back to out.println() and I couldn't figure out how to edit my post.

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Great! If my answer worked for you, please mark it as correct by clicking the tick next to it!

Comment: I updated the code to better account for the HTTP Protocol.